# TCP Listener in internet PC, how can i connect that PC with specific Ip? c#

Tags: tcp

I am trying run TCP Listener in internet PC, So its get dynamic IP address from the internet provider.Each time the IP address was dynamically changed. So Its need static Ip for the connection. Static Ip cost is very high. So How can i know the ip changed in my PC from the internet provider or else any other solution?. Any notification  c# api for dns ip changed.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Vempo:I am connecting that internet pc from tcp client. each time i need the dynamically assigned Ip address from the internet provider. so i need to the changed ip address to connect that pc

Answer (score 1):

If you need an outside client to connect to your dynamic IP, you could use dynamic DNS updates. Google for dyndns, for instance. If you really want a static IP, use IPv6. You'll (probably) need to create a tunnel for that. There are a few providers that provide that service free of cost.

Comment: Could you please tell me that any one provider?

Comment: Is there possible they give a c# api for the notification

Comment: I'm absolutely no Windows programmer, but I'd combine these two facilities:

 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759178.aspx